# I can't enter the chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, chat

[http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/beta-access http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/error_chat.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/error_chat.png)

It doesn't ask me for the beta password (this is a different machine than before where I never authenticated)

Comment: I happened to just try on a machine I haven't authenticated with yet, and got the password prompt as usual

Comment: well, I see the cat even without css...

Comment: try logging out of meta and back in to get a new cookie.

Comment: @Jared, logging out and back in solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging out and logging back in - I remember @balpha saying somewhere that an old cookie can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. clearing your domain cookies
2. logging out of the parent site (in this case Meta) and then back in first.

It is possible to have issues if you have a very old cookie.